# NameError: name 'i' is not defined num_Tabs

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
for i in range(i, num_Tabs):
    openTab(tabs=num_Tabs)
```

is returning with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[private file name]", line 27, in <module>
    for i in range(i, num_Tabs):
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

please bare in mind that I cannot program and am changing someones code based off of everything I find here.

Comment: You should provide more info e.g. What you want to get, otherwise all solutions are just suppositions

Answer (score 1):

Obviously i isn't defined. i is like a variable and python evaluate the right hand side first before assigning to the variable i. So what python interpreter sees     range(i, num_Tabs), the start value isn't defined yet hence the error. Use an integer as start value instead.  Note default is 0 i.e.    for i in range(i, num_Tabs):

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to start from zero in your range change your code to:

```
for i in range(num_Tabs):
    openTab(tabs=num_Tabs)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a for i in range
`for i in range(a,b)`
the first parameter `a` is the parameter the `for` uses as a start, the second one `b` is the ending parameter, since `i` was not previously defined, it is giving you that error.

The way you should declare that is
`for i in range(starting,ending)`

However if you want the for to start on a determined i variable, i recommend you do not use i as the iterator, rather:

```
i = 1
for x in range(i,ending):
```

For more information about the range function visit: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't created any variable, the program is generating an error, instead of writing i in the for loop, you have to use any integral value. Either you have to create a variable named i and assign some value to it.